# PowerMokito 1.7.4 @Spy annotation is not working

Tags: powermockito

I am using TestNg with PowerMocktion 1.7.4. @Spy is not working.
It's throwing below exception

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Cannot create a @Spy for
>   'service' field because the *instance* is missing

Example of correct usage of @Spy:

```
@Spy List mock = new LinkedList();

@PrepareForTest(StaticClass.class)
public class UsingPowerMockTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

@Spy
ServiceTest service;

@BeforeMethod
public void before() throws Exception {

    //service = PowerMockito.spy(new ServiceTest());
    mockStatic(StaticClass.class);
}



@Test
public void should_mock_static_method() {

    PowerMockito.when(StaticClass.randomGenerator(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn("asd");
    String randomString = service.getRandomString(20);
    System.out.println(randomString);

}

}
```

Comment: it's working when I am creating Spy like <br> service = PowerMockito.spy(new ServiceTest())

Comment: because spying is done on regular objects/beans and not on classes. So PowerMockito.spy(new ServiceTest()) will work